# How to parse a large XML file in Haskell with limited amount of resources?

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing, profiling

I want to extract information from a large XML file (around 20G) in Haskell. Since it is a large file, I used SAX parsing functions from [Hexpath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hexpat-0.20.9/docs/Text-XML-Expat-SAX.html).

Here is a simple code I tested:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Text.XML.Expat.SAX as Sax

parse :: FilePath -> IO ()
parse path = do
    inputText <- L.readFile path
    let saxEvents = Sax.parse defaultParseOptions inputText :: [SAXEvent Text Text]
    let txt = foldl' processEvent "" saxEvents
    putStrLn txt
```

After activating profiling in Cabal, it says that `parse.saxEvents` took 85% of allocated memory. I also used `foldr` and the result is the same.

If `processEvent` becomes complex enough, the program crashes with a `stack space overflow` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to look on a streaming solution: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit

Comment: What does `processEvent` do? Does it use `++` on the accumulator string? Also, do you run out of only stack space or RAM too? Please post some RAM usage stats (e. g. the `+RTS -s` flag output). Also, what's your GHC version? After GHC 7.8 stack the stack can grow to 80% of RAM by default.

Comment: @Sibi hexpat already has a streaming interface, just as xml-conduit does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what `processEvent` is like. In principle, it ought to be unproblematic to use lazy `ByteString` for a strict left fold over lazily generated input, so I'm not sure what is going wrong in your case. But one ought to use streaming-appropriate types when dealing with gigantic files!

In fact, `hexpat` does have 'streaming' interface (just like `xml-conduit`). It  uses the not-too-well known [`List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List) library and [the rather ugly `List` class it defines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List-0.5.2/docs/Data-List-Class.html#t:List).  In principle the [`ListT` type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List-0.5.2/docs/Control-Monad-ListT.html#t:ListT) from the List package should work well. I gave up quickly because of a lack of combinators, and wrote an appropriate instance of the ugly `List` class for a wrapped version of `Pipes.ListT` which I then used to export ordinary `Pipes.Producer` functions like `parseProduce`. The trivial manipulations needed for this are appended below as `PipesSax.hs`

Once we have `parseProducer` we can convert a ByteString or Text Producer into a Producer of `SaxEvents` with Text or ByteString components. Here are some simple operations. I was using a 238M "input.xml"; the programs never need more than 6 mb of memory, to judge from looking at `top`.

-- `Sax.hs` Most of the IO actions use a `registerIds` pipe defined at the bottom which is tailored to a giant bit of xml of which this is a valid 1000 fragment http://sprunge.us/WaQK

```
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import PipesSax ( parseProducer )
import Data.ByteString ( ByteString )
import Text.XML.Expat.SAX 
import Pipes  -- cabal install pipes pipes-bytestring 
import Pipes.ByteString (toHandle, fromHandle, stdin, stdout )
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified System.IO as IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Char8

sax :: MonadIO m => Producer ByteString m () 
                 -> Producer (SAXEvent ByteString ByteString) m ()
sax =  parseProducer defaultParseOptions

-- stream xml from stdin, yielding hexpat tagstream to stdout;
main0 :: IO ()
main0 =  runEffect $ sax stdin >-> P.print

-- stream the extracted 'IDs' from stdin to stdout
main1 :: IO ()
main1 = runEffect $ sax stdin >-> registryIds >-> stdout

-- write all IDs to a file
main2 =  
 IO.withFile "input.xml" IO.ReadMode $ \inp -> 
 IO.withFile "output.txt" IO.WriteMode $ \out -> 
   runEffect $ sax (fromHandle inp) >-> registryIds >-> toHandle out 

-- folds:
-- print number of IDs
main3 =  IO.withFile "input.xml" IO.ReadMode $ \inp -> 
           do n <- P.length $ sax (fromHandle inp) >-> registryIds
              print n

-- sum the meaningful part of the IDs - a dumb fold for illustration
main4 =  IO.withFile "input.xml" IO.ReadMode $ \inp ->
         do let pipeline =  sax (fromHandle inp) >-> registryIds >-> P.map readIntId
            n <- P.fold (+) 0 id pipeline
            print n
  where
   readIntId :: ByteString -> Integer
   readIntId = maybe 0 (fromIntegral.fst) . Char8.readInt . Char8.drop 2

-- my xml has tags with attributes that appear via hexpat thus:
-- StartElement "FacilitySite" [("registryId","110007915364")] 
-- and the like. This is just an arbitrary demo stream manipulation.
registryIds :: Monad m => Pipe (SAXEvent ByteString ByteString) ByteString m ()
registryIds = do 
  e <- await  -- we look for a 'SAXEvent'
  case e of -- if it matches, we yield, else we go to the next event
    StartElement "FacilitySite" [("registryId",a)] -> do yield a
                                                         yield "\n"
                                                         registryIds
    _ -> registryIds
```

-- 'library': PipesSax.hs

This just newtypes Pipes.ListT to get the appropriate instances. We don't export anything to do with `List` or `ListT` but just use the standard Pipes.Producer concept.

```
{-#LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module PipesSax (parseProducerLocations, parseProducer) where 
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Text.XML.Expat.SAX
import Data.List.Class
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Pipes  
import qualified Pipes.Internal as I

parseProducer
  :: (Monad m, GenericXMLString tag, GenericXMLString text) 
  => ParseOptions tag text
  -> Producer ByteString m () 
  -> Producer (SAXEvent tag text) m ()
parseProducer opt  = enumerate . enumerate_ 
                     . parseG opt 
                     . Select_ . Select

parseProducerLocations
  :: (Monad m, GenericXMLString tag, GenericXMLString text) 
  => ParseOptions tag text
  -> Producer ByteString m () 
  -> Producer (SAXEvent tag text, XMLParseLocation) m ()
parseProducerLocations opt = 
  enumerate . enumerate_ . parseLocationsG opt . Select_ . Select  

newtype ListT_ m a = Select_ { enumerate_ :: ListT m a }
    deriving (Functor, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadIO
             , Applicative, Alternative, Monoid, MonadTrans)

instance Monad m => List (ListT_ m) where
 type ItemM (ListT_ m) = m
 joinL = Select_ . Select . I.M . liftM (enumerate . enumerate_) 
 runList   = liftM emend  . next  . enumerate . enumerate_
   where 
     emend (Right (a,q)) = Cons a (Select_ (Select q))
     emend _ = Nil
```